# Firestore slow query / inconsistent query performance in Vue2 Project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2

Ever since I upgraded my Vue2 project from sdk8.0 to sdk10, the query became insanely slow.
There are two requests in one page:

1. Request1 returns about 2k data
2. Request2 returns about 4k data.

If I singly make only one request, the performance is fine. Here is the time cost of each request:

1. Request1 ~ 2000ms
2. Request2 ~ 5000ms

But sending Request2 after Request1, the speed of Request2 became VERY SLOW, like about 50000ms.
Through performance tab of Chrome, I notice that the Request2 after Request1, defineReactive function cost so many time.

So what is the problem?

I stored the data from request, I tried to use Object.freeze(), everything went fine. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

```js
async onLoad() {
  this.loading = true;
  const start = Date.now();
  this.projectList = [];
  const searchParams = {
    ...};
    const projects = await getSchedulingProjects(searchParams, this.$db);
  this.refKeys = [];
  this.projectList = projects.map((item) => {
    return this.getNewItem(item);
  });
  this.timeCost = Date.now() - start;
  this.loading = false;
}
async function getSchedulingProjects(args, db) {
  const { searchProjectId = null } = args;
  let queryRef = db.collection('project');
  if (searchProjectId) {
    const searchProjectIdArr = String(searchProjectId).split(',');
    queryRef = queryRef.where('project_id', 'in', searchProjectIdArr);
  }
  return queryRef.get();
}
```

I also notice that some value of the data is firebase DocumentReference type

Comment: Please share your code, otherwise, it would be difficult to help you.

Comment: thx, I added the code now

Comment: If you are using Firebase Web Client SDK v10, I would recommend that you use the new "modular API" and not the "namespaced API".  But I don't think this will affect your results.  So I recommend that you put timings around the actual API calls to know that this is where the time is (or is not) going.  For example put a console.log() before and after the call to `queryRef.get()`.  I don't know Vue, but `.get()` is an asynchronous function so typically you would be marking `getSchedulingProjects()` as being `async`

Comment: The project used old version sdk for a long time, I firstly upgraded to sdk10, used the compat/app, and try to replace the  "namespaced API" later. But I also tried  "modular API", the performance stayed the same, so I think is not the API problem.

Comment: Is the large dataset problem? Defining a large dataset with a high nesting level maybe time-consuming. But when i used sdk8, the problem doesn't exist

Comment: The size of the data set under consideration is not a factor in the performance of Firestore queries on the server. That's its main USP. --- Can you reproduce the problem with two hard-coded queries, rather than with the dynamic query building that we can't see? If so, can you show those queres as well as the timing calls that Greg asked for?